# How can you delete the last Authoritative Page for a search service application

Tags: 2013, enterprise-search, authoritative-pages

I am having this problem on SharePoint 2013, but the same question/answer may apply to SharePoint 2010.

The Authoritative Pages for a search service application start out with no pages specified, but with the "most authoritative pages" field is required.

Once you add a "most authoritative page" it doesn't appear to want to go away.  I have tried removing them with PowerShell (http://www.dontpapanic.com/blog/?p=319), but it appears to silently fail when deleting the last URL left.  It seems like the first URL entered never wants to go away.

Comment: If you cannot remove it, can you at least provide the URL of your most authoritative site? (As a work around.)

Comment: I can add more authoritative sites, but cannot remove the first one I created.  Since the one I cannot review is simply a document URL (and not a site URL), It is basically an annoyance that shouldn't really matter, but it bothers me that I cannot clean things up.  I saw this in another test environment as well, so this appears to be a bug.  I'd be interested in knowing if anyone else sees this.

Answer (score 1):

I just used the following to remove all of my Authoritative pages.

```
Get-SPEnterpriseSearchQueryAuthority -SearchApplication $ssa
-Owner $owner | Remove-SPEnterpriseSearchQueryAuthority -SearchApplication $ssa
-Owner $owner
```

In the UI I can now confirm what you are saying. It restored the one original page from the initial build of the farm.

I can add a new URL and remove the original though, leaving only the new URL.

Are you saying that your original URL will not go away? (You need to have at least one URL in the list.)

```
Started with http://foo
Removed http://foo and added http://bar.
Ran PowerShell and removed http://bar. http://foo is restored.
Replaced http://foo with http://bar and only http://bar remains.
```